# SQLite best practice: manipulate in-memory DataTable or query DB?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I'm new to SQLite and relational DB's in general.  I am using VS2015 and VB.NET, and when my app loads I am using a SELECT * query to load a DataTable field, which is displayed in Virtual Mode through a DGV.

After the initial loading, if I want to update a row, is it best practice to directly manipulate the DataTable object, then call Update() on a DataAdapter, or should I just run a UPDATE query directly on the DB instead?  Are they essentially the same result?  I would think for large amounts of updates, the in-memory solution would be the way to go, but I wanted to see if anyone on here had some insight I am probably overlooking.

Comment: I've voted to close your question because it's off-topic for SO.  That said, if you have a `DataTable`, use it.  Otherwise, you're still going to have to modify the `DataTable` after modifying the database anyway.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Ok thanks, I would have marked this as the answer but it's fine to have it closed.  This is actually exactly what I was looking for.  :)